Biblatex does't print the magazine number
Biblatex does't print the magazine number in first referance.
How to fix it?
I'm using TeX Live 2023(Biber 2.19).
MWE:
% !TeX program = lualatex
% !TeX encoding = utf-8
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[main=english]{babel}
%
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{bob,
    author = {Bob, Bob},
    title = {A Nice Title 1},
    journal = {Annual Review of Nothing},
    year = {2011},
    number = {5(83)}, % <--- disappears here
    pages = {35-40},
    langid = {english}
}

@article{john,
    author = {John, John},
    title = {A Nice Title 2},
    journal = {Annual Review of Something},
    year = {2009},
    number = {12},
    pages = {63-66},
    langid = {english}
}
\end{filecontents}
%
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
language=auto,
autolang=other,
citestyle=gost-numeric,
style=gost-numeric,
sorting=none
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 

\begin{document}
    Here is something~\cite{bob} very interesting~\cite{john}.
    \printbibliography
\end{document}



Have you checked the biber log? 5(83) seems a strange value. Sure this is not vol 5 number 83 or similar?

That's right "No. 5(83)". @daleif

I'm a bit confused here: biblatex does print the number field for me and it is shown in your screenshot as well. It doesn't show the string "No." here, because "5(83)" does not pass the test that checks if the contents of the field is an integer. Can you explain why you have this particular input? Ideally with a real-world example? Do you actually want something like volume = {5}, number = {83},?

Yes, this is a real example,@moewe . I found a solution. Add: \DeclareNumChars*{()} Thanks to all.

So if that's the number, which volume is it in?

Hrmm. I meant a completely non-made up .bib entry (the "5(83)" may not be made up, but the rest of the entry appears to be made up). Anyway, if you've found your solution, please post it as an answer in the answer section below and accept it, so that other people can benefit from your solution as well and the question can be marked as resolved.
